# Is it possible to get a value in a structure by field name without implementing the `Index` trait?

Tags: rust

I have a struct:

```
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String
}
```

I want to get the field by a variable:

```
let person = Person {
    first_name: "Chris".to_string(),
    last_name: "Tom".to_string()
};

let field_name = "last_name";
```

Is it possible to use some code like this without implementing the `Index` trait?

```
let field_value = person[field_name]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You will need to write *something* to do the lookup yourself.  Be that implementing `Index` or a method.